# Running multiple queries in one MySQL statement to get number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, execution

I am trying to make a forum post count. I have two tables:

`Threads` and `Replies`.

The `Threads` table is structured like this:

```
Id
ForumId
Last Poster
Title
Text
```

The `Replies` table is structured like so:

```
Id
ThreadId
Text
```

What I'm trying to do is **get the total number of replies and threads in one ForumId**.
I've looked all over Google, and still no luck.

How would I go about doing this?

*The reason I am doing this is because I have too many posts and my old method was slow.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query returns one row with two fields, containing the reply count and thread count for the given forum *(replace `1` with the actual forum ID)*:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) ReplyCount, COUNT(DISTINCT ThreadId) ThreadCount
FROM Replies
WHERE ThreadId IN (SELECT Id FROM Threads WHERE ForumId = 1)
```

You can also use this syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) ReplyCount, COUNT(DISTINCT ThreadId) ThreadCount
FROM Replies JOIN Threads ON Replies.ThreadId = Threads.Id
WHERE ForumId = 1
```

Or even this:

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Replies JOIN Threads ON Replies.ThreadId = Threads.Id
        WHERE ForumId = 1
    ) ReplyCount,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Threads
        WHERE ForumId = 1
    ) ThreadCount
```

---

BTW, you'd need to properly support the query with indexes for good performance. At the first glance, this includes indexing `Replies.ThreadId` and `Threads.ForumId` (in addition to "normal" PK indexes). For a nice introduction to the topic of indexing and performance, I warmly recommend reading [Use The Index Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)

But also beware of the cost you pay for secondary indexes, in case you are using the InnoDB storage engine (see the "Disadvantages of clustering" section in [this article](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/)).

Answer (score 1):

[Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) is your best friend here.

To select number of threads + number of replies in each ForumId

```
select ForumId, count(*) from Threads,Replies
where Threads.id=Replies.ThreadId
group by ForumId
```

If you know the ForumId (lets call it x):

```
select count(*) from Threads,Replies
where Threads.id=Replies.ThreadId and ForumId=x
```

Basic steps to run query with php and mysql_ functions

1. $sql = one of the above queries
2. $result = mysql_query($sql);
3. $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
4. $count = $result[0];
5. echo $count

Comment: How exactly would I get that number of rows now? mysql_num_rows? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: In the second query there should only be one row with one column. result=mysql_query($sql); result[0] would be the number you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, when I print it out, I get resources, and when I echo the result[0], I get nothing. I tried printing it into a string, it returned "".

Comment: try adding mysql_fetch_array(result) between query and [0]. if you are using php you will need to add a $ in front of all uses of result.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with:

$_POSTS = mysql_fetch_array($_POSTS);
$_POSTS = $_POSTS[0];

Comment: Awesome. I updated my original answer to clarify. If my answer was helpful I would appreciate if you could accept it. This will tell you how and why it benefits everyone here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work